# Proving the monotone decreasing and find the limit ??

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a,b$ be positive real number. Set $x_0 =a$ and $x_{n+1}= \frac{1}{x_n^{-1}+b}$ for $n≥0$

(a) Prove that $x_n$ is monotone decreasing.

(b) Prove that the limit exists and find it.

Any help? I don't know where to start.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove the sequence is monotone decreasing and find the limit?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290829/prove-the-sequence-is-monotone-decreasing-and-find-the-limit)

Answer (score 2):

HINTS: A good place to start is with the function

$$f(x)=\frac1{x^{-1}+b}=\frac1{\frac1x+b}=\frac{x}{1+bx}\;,$$

since your recurrence is $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$. In order to show that the sequence is monotone decreasing, you’d like to show that $f(x_n)<x_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. Clearly $x_0=a>0$, and since $b>0$, it’s easy to see that $x_n>0$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$. So if $x>0$, when do we have $f(x)<x$? Clearly this happens if and only if $1+bx>1$; why, and when does that happen?

For (b), remember that a bounded monotone sequence **always** converges. Once you’ve done (a), you know that this sequence is monotone decreasing and bounded below by $0$, so it converges. To find the limit, use the fact that $f$ is a continuous function on the positive reals: if $L=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n$, then

$$f(L)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n+1}=L\;.$$

That is, $L$ is a fixed point of the function $f$. What is (or are) the fixed point(s) of $f$?

Answer (score 0):

clearly this is a sequence of positive real numbers.
Let $x_n^{-1}=k$. Then $x_{n+1}=\frac{k}{1+kb} < k$.
Hence $x_{n+1}<x_n$ and (a) follows

this is a monotonic decreasing sequence of positive real numbers hence bounded below by zero.now monotonic decreasing sequence bounded below converges to its infimum.So limit exist.I hope now you can calculate the limit.

Answer (score 0):

To prove the limit exists use the fact every decreasing bounded below sequence is convergent. To find the limit just assume $ \lim_{n\to \infty} x_n = x = \lim_{n\to \infty} x_{n+1} $ and solve the equation for $x$

$$ x=\frac{1}{1/x+b} .$$